# Protected multilib versions error when updating yum in Fedora 16

Tags: linux, yum, fedora-16

I have Fedora 16 installed. I'm facing some in issues when updating `yum`.

```
Error: Protected multilib versions: 
flash-plugin-11.2.202.233-release.i386 != flash-plugin-11.1.102.55-release.x86_64
```

Answer (score 5):

This should solve your problem:

`$ sudo yum upgrade --setopt=protected_multilib=false --skip-broken`

Comment: This is generally a bad thing to do, even says so in the output from this.  `       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `--enablerepo updates-testing` to the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem.

What I did was disable the adobe repo, based on this post [fedoraforum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=162296).
Then I removed the flashplugin. yum remove flash-plugin
Then I reinstalled only the 64bit version of the flash_plugin ([install](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-adobe-flash-player-10-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)).

This seems to be working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem myself.
So, the thing is that the 32 bit version (i.e. i386) is not the same as the 64 bit one.
I needed the 32 bit version, so I had to manually do a `yum update` on each lib that I needed, so that the 32 and the 64 bit versions match the same version (i.e. `11.2.202.233` vs `11.1.102.55`).

Hope it helps you